# Rails: include code in view immediately after sign_in through devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using a js live chat widget on my rails site and I want to add a little javascript to my template after somebody signs in (it's basically telling me I've got one of my users of a particular type looking at the site).

I'm thinking that

```
after_sign_in_path_for
```

Seems like the right place, but how do I pass a parameter (e.g.

```
{new_session:true}
```

) to a method that looks like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
  if request.referer == sign_in_url
    super
  else
    stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
  end
end
```

i.e.

```
root_path(new_session:true)
```

is straightforward, but what on earth do I do with the super, stored_location_for and request.referer...?

Seems a really ugly way to do it, in any case...

Any better ideas?

Is there a sensible way to do this in devise. 
e.g.

```
-if current_user.just_signed_in?
  :javascript
    _blah_de_blah.blah{blah;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible hack and I'd be delighted if someone came up with a better way... but...

```
-if current_user.current_sign_in_at > Time.now - 5.seconds
    :javascript  
      #some javascript code here...
```

Basically does the job required. 
Obviously if they hit multiple pages before that 5 seconds is up it's going to post the code multiple times...